# What is the Arizal's full name

Tags: arizal

What is the full name of the Arizal,I know it's Rav Yitzchak Luria (Ashkanazi) but I never saw his full name,like ...ben... What's his name including his father's name?

Comment: 5 seconds on Wikipedia tells me his dad's name was Shelomo. Did you try searching for this at all? What did you find?

Comment: It's funny you mention that I checked a bunch of websites and I see that Wikipedia does mention it ,supersised no other site did

Comment: This may not be the greatest question, but I'm not following the reason that it was voted on-hold. It doesn't look like a history question. What if I asked who Nun's father was?

Comment: @DanF Off topic. What if you asked who msh210's father was? Also off topic. It's a question about Jewish individuals unrelated to Judaism.

Comment: @DoubleAA I see. You're right, I should have asked who YOUR father is / was ;-)

Answer (score 4):

See [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/biography/Luria.html). It's Shlomo.